# Get struct tag without pointer

Tags: pointers, go, struct, reflection

I was creating a simple marshaler for fixed with text into struct in Go, as detailed [here](https://github.com/iarief/tts).

The marshaler functions as I expected now, albeit still lacking some features. What I got stuck in is in the marshal function.

The relevant code is as follow

```
func Marshal(obj interface{}) (str string, err error) {
...
    elemsType := reflect.TypeOf(obj).Elem()
```

As you can see, I tried to mimic the json package's marshal signature. Then only problem is when I tried to pass by value to the marshal function, the `reflect.TypeOf` returns a different type than the one I pass into it. The function can only executed if I'm passing pointer to the marshal function.

This works

```
user := User{"johnjohnjohn", "the", "doe", "smart", 26}
res, err := Marshal(&user)
```

This doesn't

```
user := User{"johnjohnjohn", "the", "doe", "smart", 26}
res, err := Marshal(user)
```

Is there any way to just pass by value, and then get the struct tag inside the marshal function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to work on values, don't call `Type.Elem()` on the reflect type. To handle both (pointers and non-pointers), check if it is of pointer type, and only then call `Type.Elem()`:

```
elemsType := reflect.TypeOf(obj)
if elemsType.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    elemsType = elemsType.Elem()
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's it.

I'm still grasping the concept of pointer in go, thanks for answering!